# Set up PHP development environment in Eclipse

Tags: php, mysql, eclipse, apache, lamp

I've already started developing in PHP, but I've had various issues with the environment: mysql server won't start, can't debug PHP code (even after defining PHP executables), installed apache2 and it didn't work, installed LAMP and still nothing, etc.

Overall, it's just been a mess, so I decided to start over(or any other fix that might pop up). That said, how can I set up a near-perfect PHP environment in Eclipse in which I can debug, run and just not have all this hassle?

I'm running Eclipse Indigo with PDT and PHP 5.3.

Comment: @close voters: "not a real question" and "not constructive" — _really?_ This is a bit open-ended but seems like a _great_ question given the specified parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Well...you can start reading this:

[How To Setup a Local PHP Development Environment in Linux Ubuntu 11.04 with Eclipse Indigo 3.7, LAMP & Xdebug](http://www.mmncs.com/2011/08/how-to-install-setup-a-local-php-development-environment-in-linux-ubuntu-11-04-with-eclipse-indigo-3-7-lamp-xdebug-developer/)

In addition I would suggest installing:

[Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project_summary.php?projectid=webtools) for your HTML/CSS development

[Eclipse Data Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project_summary.php?projectid=datatools) for your DB development. You can also use PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: I would go with this. This is your easiest way to set it up.

Comment: The first link is dead.